# SQL query conversion error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am getting an error on a T-SQL Query.

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 21
>   The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

My query so far looks like this

```
use Test

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MetricsServerUserAudit') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN   
    BULK INSERT #MetricsServerUserAudit 
    FROM 'C:\QPR_Logs\Audit\MetricsServerAudit.txt'
    WITH (FIRSTROW = 1)             

IF OBJECT_ID('MetricsServerUserAudit') IS NOT NULL
begin
    INSERT INTO dbo.MetricsServerUserAudit(DateStamp, [TIME], [DATE],[USER_LOGIN], [USER_NAME], [MODEL_NAME], [OPERATION], [TARGET_USER],[TARGET_GROUP], [ELEMENT_TYPE_NAME], [ELEMENT_TYPE_PERMISSION], [OBJECT_NAME], [OBJECT_PERMISSION])
        SELECT
            CONVERT(CHAR(10), [DATE], 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(11),[TIME], 108) as DateStamp,  
            CONVERT(CHAR(11), [TIME], 108) AS [TIME], 
            CONVERT(CHAR(10), [DATE], 101) AS [DATE],
            [USER_LOGIN], [USER_NAME], [MODEL_NAME], [OPERATION],
            [TARGET_USER], [TARGET_GROUP], 
            [ELEMENT_TYPE_NAME], [ELEMENT_TYPE_PERMISSION],
            [OBJECT_NAME], [OBJECT_PERMISSION]  
        FROM
            dbo.MetricsServerUserAudit 
        WHERE
            LEN([TIME]) = 8 
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MetricsServerUserAudit)

    drop table #MetricsServerUserAudit
end
end
else
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MetricsServerUserAudit') IS NULL
    begin
        CREATE TABLE #MetricsServerUserAudit
        (
            [TIME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [DATE] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,  
            [MODEL_NAME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [OPERATION] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [TARGET_USER] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [TARGET_GROUP] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [ELEMENT_TYPE_NAME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [ELEMENT_TYPE_PERMISSION] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [OBJECT_NAME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
            [OBJECT_PERMISSION] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL  
        )

        BULK INSERT #MetricsServerUserAudit 
        FROM 'C:\QPR_Logs\Audit\MetricsServerAudit.txt'
        WITH (FIRSTROW = 1)

        IF OBJECT_ID('MetricsServerUserAudit') IS NULL
            CREATE TABLE MetricsServerUserAudit
            (
                [DateStamp] DATETIME NOT NULL,
                [TIME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                [DATE] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                [USER_LOGIN] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,    
                [USER_NAME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                [MODEL_NAME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                [OPERATION] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                [TARGET_USER] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,   
                [TARGET_GROUP] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                [ELEMENT_TYPE_NAME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                [ELEMENT_TYPE_PERMISSION] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,
                [OBJECT_NAME] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL,   
                [OBJECT_PERMISSION] nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
             )

        INSERT INTO MetricsServerUserAudit(DateStamp,[TIME],[DATE],[USER_LOGIN],[USER_NAME],[MODEL_NAME],[OPERATION],[TARGET_USER], [TARGET_GROUP],[ELEMENT_TYPE_NAME],[ELEMENT_TYPE_PERMISSION],[OBJECT_NAME],[OBJECT_PERMISSION])
            select 
                convert(char(10),[DATE],101) + ' ' + convert(char(11),[TIME],108) as DateStamp, 
                convert(char(11),[TIME],108) as [TIME],convert(char(10),[DATE],101) as[DATE],
                [USER_LOGIN], [USER_NAME],
                [MODEL_NAME], [OPERATION], 
                [TARGET_USER], [TARGET_GROUP],
                [ELEMENT_TYPE_NAME], [ELEMENT_TYPE_PERMISSION],
                [OBJECT_NAME], [OBJECT_PERMISSION]  
            from 
                #MetricsServerUserAudit 
            where 
                LEN([TIME]) = 8 
                and not exists (select * from MetricsServerUserAudit)

        drop table #MetricsServerUserAudit
end
```

Line 21 that they talk about is

```
Insert into MetricsServerUserAudit(DateStamp, [TIME], [DATE], [USER_LOGIN], [USER_NAME], [MODEL_NAME], [OPERATION], [TARGET_USER],  [TARGET_GROUP], [ELEMENT_TYPE_NAME], [ELEMENT_TYPE_PERMISSION], [OBJECT_NAME], [OBJECT_PERMISSION])
```

Could someone explain to me why I'm getting this error? Is the design of the table wrong? Is my query not right? If there is a better way for the query do let me know please. I want to learn more.

Comment: convert(char(10),[DATE],101) .... seems char(10) is to small for 101 format of date ... try char(30)

Comment: select convert(char(10),[DATE],101) + ' ' + convert(char(11),[TIME],108) as DateStamp, ...
Convert this to datetime explicitly

Comment: @ChristophBethge Try `SET DATEFORMAT xxx` where xxx is `dmy` or any format you actually use

Comment: You have a date or time value that is not using format "101" or "108".  The result is that you cannot convert it to a string using that format.

Comment: Store dates as a `datetime` datatype, **not** as `varchar`. Datatypes exist for a reason, use the appropriate datatype